# How can I run a Perl script with ActivePerl?

Tags: perl

I just recently installed ActivePerl 5.12.2.1202 on my Windows XP in `C:/Perl`. I am new to Perl scripting.

I just want to run a Perl program which contains one `print` statement, which I saved in Notepad with the name `ex.pl`.

1. How can I run this Perl program?
2. Can I use an editor for typing a Perl script other than Notepad?
3. How do I use ActivePerl?

Comment: What's the difference between ActivePerl and StrawberryPerl?

Answer (score 11):

- Run Perl program from **command prompt**

  `start->run>cmd` (command prompt will appear), write `perl full_path_of_your_script`, 
  like
  `C:\> perl hello.pl` `#This assumes that perl is in your PATH environment variable.`
- There are many **Perl Editors**, you can
  used for Perl scripts like **[DzSoft](http://www.dzsoft.com/perl-editor.html)**,
  **[Perl Expess](http://www.perl-express.com/)**, **[Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit)** etc and also see http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=169668  and **[Perlfaq3](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq3.html#Is-there-an-IDE-or-Windows-Perl-Editor%3f)**- *Windows Perl Editors* for more detail.
- Have a look at http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.12/, for **ActivePerl 5.12 documentation**.

Comment: Which one is faster?
I'm using LaTex and the bibliography uses perl, but default one is extremly slow.

Answer (score 4):

Perl programs (or any other program run by an interpreter) is run by passing the script as a command-line argument to the interpreter. For example, in this case:

```
perl.exe ex.pl
```

[Padre](http://padre.perlide.org/) the Perl IDE and [Kephra](http://kephra.sourceforge.net/) are good editors for Perl.

As an alternative to ActivePerl, there is [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/).

Comment: C:/Perl/bin must be in environment PATH.

Answer (score 1):

Perl programs are run using the Perl interpreter, perl.exe.
This is normally done from the command line:

```
C:\>C:\Perl\bin\perl ex.pl
```

If perl.exe is in your `PATH` environment variable that can be shortened to:

```
C:\>perl ex.pl
```

If you opted to have *.pl files associated with Perl during installation, you can also double-click on them from Windows Explorer.

If you have *.pl files associated with Perl and add `.PL` to your `PATHEXT` environment variable you can run them like any other executable:

```
C:\>ex
```

Perl programs are just text files. They can be edited with any text editor (Padre, Kokomo, vim, emacs, Notepad++, etc.). Use whichever one you like best.

ActivePerl is just a distribution of Perl. "Using" it usually means running perl.exe to execute your program. ActivePerl also includes the [PPM](http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.12/faq/ActivePerl-faq2.html) (Perl Package Manager) utility to make it easier to install modules from CPAN, particularly if you don't have a C compiler available. Most experienced Perl developers prefer to use the [cpan](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CPAN) shell.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the other answers, I use EPIC, the Perl eclipse plugin.  I'm using Perl on a Windows 7 64 bit machine.

I still run scripts off the command line in windows using ActivePerl, but for development I like being able to dynamically step through the script line by line.

Answer (score 0):

just to not paraphrase other answers and to be more helpful (even if the post is somehow old ) i recommend using the switch "-e" to run Perl scripts if they are composed of few statements e.g

> Perl -e "print('hello')"

and of course this requires that the Perl executable is in the Path variable,if not and assuming Perl is under the folder c:\Perl , you can add it by taping :

> set %PATH%=%PATH%;c:\Perl\bin

when it comes to the choice of text editor ,I'm still using Notepad++ for almost everything ,it come with some useful features like keywords highlighting and some auto-completion capabilities.